# Type Cast Confusion

Tags: c++, casting

My professor is trying to help us understand type casting more in depth in c++ so he gave us the bit of code that is below. Can anyone explain why the output for the second cout statement is such a large number?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
float f = 5.0;
int i = f;
cout << i << endl;
cout << *((int*)&f) << endl;
```

This displays:

5

1084227584

Comment: Some search engine food for you: "floating point representation". This should answer all your questions, in detail.

Comment: _"type casting more in depth"_ - What you are doing in `*((int*)&f)` is type-_punning_ and it has _undefined behavior_ in C++

Comment: Your professor is not teaching you C++.  He is teaching you "C".  In C++ he should use `reinterpret_cast<int*>(f)`. Tell him the C++ community is trying to reach out and asks him to stop teaching "C". Anyway the cast result is a value without any practical meaning.

Comment: This may be a lesson in Undefined Behaviour. Even if `int` and `float` are the same size, they don't have the same shape. How an integer is represented is very different from how a float is represented. `int i = f;` says, "Lop off all of the floating point stuff and leave me with an integer." `*((int*)&f)`  says "Reinterpret the binary pattern of `f` and show what it would look like as an integer."

Comment: Side note: When you see this kind of explicit casting in someone's code, stop and take a closer look for bugs. Do not trust it until you've personally verified it. Maybe it's OK, but too often it's not, and if you fix the problem now you'll have less debugging to do later.

Comment: @PepijnKramer `reinterpret_cast<int*>(f)` is casting the *value* of `f` rather than the *address* of `f`, which is what `(int*)&f` is doing. You forgot the `&` on `f`, eg: `*reinterpret_cast<int*>(&f)`.  Alternatively, cast `f` using a reference instead of a pointer: `reinterpret_cast<int&>(f)`

Comment: Here's a nicer way to look at what's stored in memory for the two different variable types: https://godbolt.org/z/7v4hG9WGT

Comment: @Remy you're right I missed the pointer. Me bad ;)

Comment: @user4581301 so in this situation *((int*)&f) is the address of the value that is stored in f? I am sorry, this is so confusing to me and there is a large language barrier between me and my professor that makes his lectures difficult to understand.

Comment: `&f` provides the address of `f`. The `(int*)` tells the compiler, "Ignore that `f` is a `float` and we really have the address of a `float`. I, the great and all-powerful Programmer, decree that it's OK to treat it as a pointer to an `int` and view the variable at this address as if it was an `int`." It's a very powerful ability, but when you're wrong, you've turned off all of the checking the compiler will do for you. You get no errors, no warnings, no diagnostics. You won't know anything is wrong until you see bad program behaviour. And you might not even see that until it's too late.